# Is it possible to create a FirefoxProfile and pass in saved passwords?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile

Is it possible to add passwords to a profile that's created as an instance of [`org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html)?

From Mozilla docs (*[Profiles — Where Firefox stores your bookmarks, passwords and other user data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Profiles)*), I can see that Firefox stores passwords in two files:

> - **Passwords:** Your passwords are stored in the *key3.db* and *logins.json* files. For more information, see [Password Manager - Remember, delete, change and import saved passwords in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import).

But can't see any way in the `FirefoxProfile` class to either add passwords to a profile individually, or to pass in files like *logins.json*/*key3.db*. (I can't find anything on the linked Mozilla pages either, which seem to be storing passwords as a regular user, rather than programmatically)

In my Selenium test suite, I'm creating a Firefox profile on the fly in code but am having to encode passwords (e.g. for HTTP Basic Auth on Dev servers) into URLs like this:

```
http://user:pass@localhost/example.html
```

(I know I could create an entire profile and add that to Git, to be passed around, but would like to avoid that if I can)

Comment: Which version of firefox do you need this solution to support?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56, I've got FF47 installed on my work machine, so I'd say that or better — if you have a solution that works e.g. just on latest version I'd be happy to upgrade!

Comment: Selenium Java support for Firefox versions after 47.0.1 depend on geckodriver.  You would need Selenium V3.0.2 (as of this writing). There are issues with geckodriver. "Marionette and geckodriver are not yet feature complete. This means it does not yet offer full conformance with the WebDriver standard or complete compatibility with Selenium." So FF47 may be the latest version that something can be done. Let me play around with it.

Answer (score 2):

I read through the [selenium firefoxprofile code for v53.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.53.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.java) and didn't see anything obvious. However, you could [copy those two files from the existing profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile#w_passwords) into the default profile created by selenium.  You only need the location of the newly generated default firefoxprofile which you can get (dynamically) when executing:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
System.out.println(">> path to profile=" + profile.layoutOnDisk().getAbsolutePath());
// Copy the two files
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try this out yet, but sounds like it should get me to what I need. Shame that you can't do it via the API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create in firefox profile
Click the menu button and then click ExitQuit . Note: You can use -P , -p or -ProfileManager (any of them should work). Press Return. The Firefox Profile Manager (Choose User Profile) window should open.

Comment: Hi Amit, I was asking about creating adding passwords to a profile created programmatically through Selenium Java API, rather than manually creating  a profile using the Profile Manager

Comment: Oh I am sorry @anotherdave